# Should I return null when only HTTP status code is important?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I'm programming a reset password system in nodejs + JWT. In some functions I dont't really need to send nothing as answer to the frontend, just is important the HTTP Status Code.. But i'm not sure if it's a good practice returning a null value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use status code `204` instead

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/204

Answer (score 2):

Sure, that could work if the status code is the only information you need to convey in the request. There's even an Express method designed for exactly this - to send the status code (and in the body the corresponding message for the code, just in case it's useful, though you're free to ignore it). See [`res.sendStatus`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendStatus). `sendStatus` would be a bit more appropriate than `.send(null)` though.